# Text inside navigation bar automatically moved to the right on other screen sizes

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, navigationbar

I've been trying to figure this out for days now.
I have a problem with the text on my navigation bar (this also happens to other lists that are between `<div>`s) it behaves weirdly and keeps moving to the right when I look at my website on a  screen other than the one I'm programming on even though I use percentages. I think the problem lays in that the divdoesn't adjust correctly to the smaller or bigger getting screen.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdaLd.png) is how It looks on my laptop and this is how I want it to be on screens of bigger or smaller size but as I said on different screens it moves to the right.

I'm a new programmer so if u see useless code please ignore it I'm still learning a lot, but It seems I just can't figure this out.

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">

<ol id="navbartext">

    <a href="buynow.html"><li class="navbarhover" >Buy Now</li></a>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="lijn"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <a href="news.html"><li href="news.html" class="navbarhover">News</li></a>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="lijn"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <a href="media.html"><li href="media.html" class="navbarhover">Media</li></a>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="lijn"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <a href="contact.html"><li href="contact.html" class="navbarhover">Contact</li></a>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="lijn"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <a href="aboutus.html"><li href="aboutus.html" class="navbarhover">About Us</li></a>

</ol></div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbartext{
color: white;
font-family: Futura, Verdana, Arial;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 11%;
margin-top: 1%;
font-size: 120%;
padding: 0%;
}

#navbar{
position: absolute;
height: 5%;
width: 50%;
top: 20%;
left:50%;
margin-left: -25.1%;
padding: 5px;
border: 3px solid #008CBA;
background-color: #333;
margin-top: 2.5%;
font-size: 100%;
}    
li{
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
font-size: 102%;
}
```

If you need to see more code please tell me.
Thanks for reading I really need help with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
  background-color:orange;
  list-style-type: none;
  display:block
}
li{
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
#wrapper{
  margin-top:5%;
  height:5%;
  margin-left:18%;
  margin-right:18%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Arma</li></a>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>Sar</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>VCS</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>VCS</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>VCS</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>VCS</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>VCS</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is example.Other style put yourself.

Comment: Can you tell me why it would solve the problem? I don't understand it if you just give me a bunch of code, please explain. Thanks

Comment: There is not any explanation.Each man use different way to solve problems.